# How to programmatically tell `Spring Boot` to load configuration files from `custom location` when doing JUNIT Test

Tags: spring-boot, junit

How to **programmatically** tell `Spring Boot` to load configuration `yaml` files from `custom location` when doing JUNIT Test.

In program, I could use `properties` of `SpringApplicationBuilder` to specify my custom `yaml` file .

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class SampleWebApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(SampleWebApplication.class)
        .properties("spring.config.name:application,conf",
            "spring.config.location=classpath:/viaenvironment.yaml")
        .build().run(args);

    ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
    System.out.println(environment.getProperty("app.name"));
  }
}
```

When doing JUNIT Test, how should I configure it?
I'm using `spring boot 1.5.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this option to set the spring.config.location through @TestPropertySource:

```
 @TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location = classpath:<path-to-your-yml-file>" }
```